# HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: 16 'MyDB'. XTP Engine version is 0.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In error log on SQL Server 2016, i am seeing lots of error message like this.

> 2017-08-14 20:20:41.820   spid95  [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize():
>   Database ID: [16] 'mydb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0. 2017-08-14
>   20:20:41.820  spid95  Starting up database 'mydb'

Similar message for other database as well. Please help to understand what the message is about, is it a normal or is my databases crashes frequently? Also please suggest the solution.

.

Comment: Can you include messages from before and after this?

Comment: Does this explain it: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2876739/excessive-non-usable-messages-in-sql-log-when-running-checkdb-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: I am not running DBCC CHECKDB. The log is auto generated. Does it looks like my databases crashes/

Comment: Stupid question... Does that database have in-memory usage in it? Is there a filegroup?